# Create a pod with specified name using kubectl in command line?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

Using kubectl command line, is it possible to define the exact pod name?

I have tried with

```
kubectl run $pod-name --image imageX
```

However, the resulted pod name is something like `$pod-name-xx-yyy-nnn`.
So without using a yaml file, can I define the pod name using kubectl CLI?

Comment: How I understand pod is not from k8s object which could have name determined by user. If you need the entry point to access some pod endpoint you should create the service which is connected with pod by the selector. K8S service could have the name defiened by user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`kubectl run` creates a *Deployment* by default. A *Deployment* starts a *ReplicaSet* that manages the pods/replicas... and therefore has a generated *pod name*.

### Run pod

To run a single pod you can add `--restart=Never` to the `kubectl run` command.

```
kubectl run mypod --restart=Never --image=imageX
```

Answer (score 0):

The $pod-name is a variable with some value let's say "**hello**". So when you are running the kubectl run command it will create a **deployment**. The deployment will create a **replicaset** with name "**hello-xxxx**" and the replicaset will create pod with name "**replicasetname-xxx**".
If you want to create a pod using kubectl run use the below command "*kubectl run times --generator=run-pod/v1 hello --image=busybox*".

It will create a pod with name hello. You are suppose to replace hello and image name.
Otherwise you could use "*kubectl create pod hello --image=busybox*".